# serve static files in Yesod

Tags: yesod, static-files

I'm using Yesod scaffold to build a website, and hope to serve static files from a separate domain.

I followed the  [instruction](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Serve-static-files-from-a-separate-domain) here to add the following code in the instance of Yesod App

```
urlRenderOverride master (StaticR s) =
    Just $ uncurry (joinPath master "http://static.example.com") $ renderRoute s
urlRenderOverride _ _ = Nothing
```

But got an error message

```
‘urlRenderOverride’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Yesod’
```

I searched the key word `urlRenderOverride` in Yesod book, and found it exists in [version 1.4](https://www.yesodweb.com/book-1.4/yesod-typeclass), but disappears in the newest version. Anything changed?